# Error 500 implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Tags: php, yii, implode

Every day i'm working on my shop website but today something wrong and now i can't continue to work on the website :
- I changed all sizes and now, when i wanna change a text or something else in products base, I get :

Error 500
implode(): Invalid arguments passed

...it was perfect yesterday but today not.

What is wrong with this part of yii php framework code of ProductController?

```
if(!empty($model->sizes)) {
                $sizes = explode(",", $model->sizes);
                $tmpsz = '';
                foreach($sizes as $s) {

                    $check = '';
                    $check = Sizes::model()->find(array("condition" => "name = :name", "params" => array(":name" => $s)));
                    if($check) {
                        $tmpsz[] = $s;
                    }

                }

                $model->sizes = implode(",", $tmpsz);
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should make $tmpsz an array not a string.
So `$tmpsz = '';` becomes `$tmpsz = array();`

Comment: I changed $tmpsz to array, but I get the fallowing error system say :  " Please fix the following input errors: Sizes cannot be blank."   Now then I saving my product sizes values have not been saved, they become empty ? What is it ?

Comment: That is YII error. It's impossible for me to say whats going on you should show more code.